# How to make a list with calculations based on identical values in two columns of a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to scan the column 'var2' for elements that appear in an other column 'var1' and, where they match, find the proportion 'value2'/'value1' depending on the levels of the column 'type'. The desired output would be a list or a data frame.

```
var1<- c(8, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 6, 1, 3, 7)
var2 <- c(NA,8,NA,NA,NA,3,NA,NA,5,NA,6,6,NA)
value1 <- c(4340,   NA, 3740, 3825, 3845,   NA, 4005, 2660,   NA, 3055,   NA,   NA, 5800)
value2 <- c(NA, 30, NA, NA, NA,  5, NA, NA, 15, NA,  1, 20, NA)
type <- c('Fish','Crab','Fish','Fish','Fish','Bird','Fish','Fish','Bird','Fish','Bird','Crab','Fish')
df <- data.frame(var1,var2,value1,value2,type)
```

Comment: what would be your desired output ?

Comment: Either a list or a data frame (thinking of summarize with ddply)

Comment: For example:  'var1' is a predator and var2 is prey. The number 6 appears once in var1 (i=10) and twice in var2 (i=11 and i=12). I want to calculate what the proportion 'value2' (when i=11 and i=12) is of 'value1 (when i=10)

Comment: I edited 'type' so that there are different levels of 'type' when 'var1' and 'var2' ==6

Comment: what should be the proportion for var1 = 6 ?

Comment: Its not clear what output is expected  and no we don't mean format of output (list,data.frame) but the resultant values i.e demonstrate calculation for one step, if `var1` and `var2` == 6, what is the result of value2/value1 contingent on type. Please edit you post to reflect this and a good standard is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Veerendra Gadekar it would be 1/3055 and 20/3055

Comment: considering your data is a  `data.frame` you could try to work on this `lapply(split(df, df$var2), function(x) c(x$value2/df$var1[df$var1 == unique(x$var2)]))`

Comment: @Veerendra Gadekar 
 
I made a minor modification and this works perfectly. Thank you. lapply(split(df, df$var2), function(x) c(x$value2/df$value1[df$var1 == unique(x$var2)]))

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Veerendra Gadekar who came up with the solution in a comment.

```
lapply(split(df, df$var2), 
  function(x) 
   c(x$value2/df$value1[df$var1 == unique(x$var2) & !is.na(df$value1)])
 )

#$`3`
#[1] 0.00130039
#
#$`5`
#[1] 0.005639098
#
#$`6`
#[1] 0.0003273322 0.0065466448
#
#$`8`
#[1] 0.006912442
```